# Ubuntu 13.04 randomly freezes

Tags: freeze, 13.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.04. I use Dell Studio 1558 laptop.
After upgrade my system keeps freezing randomly. One it freezes after 3 minutes, once after 1 minute and so on...
When it freezes I see all on my screen, but frozen. There is no errors, nothing.on 12.10 system works fine, even more than week. Now it stops and I see screenshot like on my desktop.

Any ideas what to do? If only I could give any logs, but I get nothing.
On Gnome I get freeze with error like on the screen attached. I haven't found any solution for that. REISUB method doesn't work here.
[image]

## EDIT:

The problem was kernel delivered with 13.04. I've installed 3.9 (rc8) and problem is gone:) But now, there is 3.9 release ([link](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel/1482194))

Hope that helped you.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question. This is about diagnosing the freeze problem, not about how to exit the machine should it freeze, which is what the linked question is about. Also the answers about what to do to diagnose/fix the freeze in the linked question all pertain to 11.10, not 13.04. Finally it seems unlikely to me that this issue is about hardware as everything was working in 12.10. Thus this seems more like a bug and the question is about how to diagnose. I think this question should be re-opened.

Comment: I don't think this is duplicate too. I've got same issues on Dell Inspiron n5110 right after updated to 13.04.

Comment: I had similair problem on an desktop with an NVidia graphics card. Is this also a setup you are using? When installing the nvidia driver the system locks up. The only workable solution is to blacklist the nouveau driver.

Comment: I wish this question would be re-opened. As edited in the original question, this problem appears to have been cleaned up in the new kernel. Unfortunately for me however running the new kernel means that i can't access wireless so my ability to test things is limited. If someone else wants to try the bug is filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1174275. Also, @Digiplace: i am not using NVidia, i am using Intel with integrated graphics. I actually think the problem may be with my wireless, see the bug.

Comment: @MorrisseyJ: see my answer to http://askubuntu.com/questions/292696/ubuntu-crashes-when-on-battery-power . Does that help?

Comment: For me this problem was caused by the Broadcom BCM43228 wireless card and the linux driver for it. I tried a whole host of things to solve it but eventually had to resort to buying an intel centrino chip which was whitelisted for my machine. Its not ideal but the problem has been solved: my wireless works wonderfully and the machine is stable.